# How to open documents and images using launcher in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, app-launcher

I am creating windows phone 8 app, I have to open docs and images using code or launcher. The problem is that those documents are not opening those are not created in MS Office, I am getting error like:

```
"Document has been damaged, cant open" and
"File Format doesn't recognized"
```

My code is here:

```
string file = "Test.xls";
var filerun = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(file);

await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(file));
```

Comment: Is document opening outside the app (directly in Office app)?

Comment: @pwas No, not opening anywhere,I do not know how to open, document is created in "open Office" Software. Thanks man!!please guide me

Comment: @csharpwinphonexaml can you show me by a code,I really do not know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
string uriToLaunch = @"http://www.contoso.com/SomeFile.docx";
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

async void DefaultLaunch()
{
    // Set the URI’s content type
    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    options.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word.document.12";

    // Launch the URI with the content type
    var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri, options);

    if (success)
    {
        // URI launched
    }
    else
    {
        // URI launch failed
    }
}
```

**Search for the right MIME type of your file.**