# Document opening issue in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, document

[image][image]

I am creating Windows Phone 8.1 application, I am trying to open document using launcher, but getting exception, and document  is not MS OFFICE document, it is created in other software. Here is my code.

```
string file = "readme.txt";
IsolatedStorageFile isf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();

if (isf.FileExists(file))
{
   isf.DeleteFile(file);
}

var filerun = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(file);
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(file));
```

I am getting error like this:

```
"Can't be Open, File Format doesn't recognize"
```

and sometimes like this:

```
"Document has been damaged"
```

I do not know how to deal with this, I am stuck here, Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error occurs from which line of code? and what is the exception type?

Comment: @kennyzx error is not occuring in between codes, after I click on document for opening, a message box appears and give me message like this: "Can't be open". Thank you. Please suggest me

Comment: @kennyzx see my edit and screen shot. thank you brother!!!

Comment: `it is created in other software`, how other software writes to the app's local folder? From your code, I see this file is created by the app: `var filerun = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(file);`

Comment: @kennyzx, yes, I meant it is created in "Open Office Software" and I want to open this document, I do not know much about this issue, so I am sorry about it. But how to solve it? Please tell me!!

Comment: OK, I understand your question and I can recreate it on my side. It looks like a limitation, ironically, you cannot launch a file created with Office hub, but only open _within_ the hub.

Comment: similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052194/how-to-open-documents-and-images-using-launcher-in-windows-phone-8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25052194/how-to-open-documents-and-images-using-launcher-in-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 2):

The file name without extension is "campaign rev 2", so the file pass to the launcher is definitely not "readme.txt".

You can pass a `LauncherOptions.DisplayApplicationPicker` to the `LaunchFileAsync` method.

```
var filerun = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(file);
var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions(){ DisplayApplicationPicker = true};
await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(filerun, options);
```

It will open a list of applications for you to choose from, so you can examine the file extension is actually .txt or .xls/.xlsx (Excel).

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcheroptions.aspx#properties), this overload is available on Windows Phone 8.1. But I have not upgraded to 8.1 yet, so I can not give you a screenshot of the Application Picker.

Screenshot from the web. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: I mean either "readme.txt" or "campaign rev 2.xls" was not opening. I gave example like "readme.txt". Thank you.

Comment: kennyzx, I use your last code but still getting an error. please see my other screen shot. Thank you.